# Ruby force close IO.popen java process

Tags: ruby, popen, kill

### How can I force quit/kill a java process that was stared with IO.popen("command", "r+")?

I am running a script a small java program from ruby doing the following:

```
pipe = IO.popen("nice -n 19 java -Xmx2g -Djava.awt.headless=true -jar java_program.jar", 'r+')
```

Then I use stdio to send arguments back and forth, like this:

```
pipe.puts "data"
result = pipe.gets
```

This works fine for most data I send, but for some the java process seems to lock up or something, and I would like to force close / kill the java process.

I am currently doing the following, which does not seem to kill the java process (from another thread which watches over this stuff):

```
thepid = nil
thepid = pipe.pid            if pipe.respond_to?(:pid)
pipe.puts('')                if pipe.respond_to?(:puts) #This is the java_program's approach to closing, writing empty string to stdio will cause it to start it's shutdown procedure.
pipe.close                   if pipe.respond_to?(:close)
Process.kill('KILL', thepid) if thepid && Process.getpgid( thepid )
```

The java process lingers and refuses to die. What can I do to actually force the process to exit (it uses lots of ram :( )

#### Also: Is there a cross platform way of doing this?

Comment: Have you tried [`popen3`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/open3/rdoc/Open3.html#method-c-popen3)? What's the result of your `kill` call? Are you sure you're targeting the correct PID? You may be killing the `nice` process but not the `java` one.

Comment: Would `popen3` make any difference? I don't know too much about it. Does it work differently than the normal `popen` except for the 3 distinct IOs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you may be seeing here is that you're killing the `nice` process and not the `java` process it launches.

You could avoid this by launching the `java` process directly and then altering the nice level using `renice` on the PID you get.

It's also worth checking that you're trying to kill the correct process. As you point out, spawning a second instance by accident would mean you're killing the wrong one.

A tool like `popen3` allows for a lot more control over the child process and gives you the ability to feed input and capture output directly.

Comment: It did not help to remove the `nice` prepend. Any other ideas?

Comment: Compare your process list with the `pid` value you've captured.

Comment: It is the right ones. Maybe I am using the wrong signals? Is `KILL` the best signal to use, or should I send `TERM` or something completely different? What will actually fore kill the process?

Comment: `KILL` is the most extreme version, it doesn't give the process a chance to shut down, and it can't be ignored. If that doesn't work, something odd is going on. Does an equivalent call from the command-line produce any meaningful errors? Are you sure the `kill` call is triggered?

Comment: I am investigating some stuff now. I think I had an odd race-condition which seemed to boot new instances. I am trying to convert to popen3 and  structure my code differently. Hopefully that will take care of my issues.

Comment: So I refactored my stuff, and yes, it solved my problems. I was getting a race condition in my shutdown procedure which caused a new instance to boot up immediately. To solve this I went from using the non-block version of `IO.popen/Open3.popen3` to the block version. This made my life a lot easier. The comment you made about "are you sure you're targeting the correct PID" is essentially the answer to this. Feel free to add it to the answer, and I will accept :)